# 1MB quota limit for a blobstore object in Google App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore, quota

I'm using  [App Engine (version 1.4.3) direct write the blobstore](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview.html#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore) in order to save images.
when I try to store an image which is larger than 1MB I get the following Exception

```
com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$RequestTooLargeException: The request to API call datastore_v3.Put() was too large.
```

I thought that the [limit for each object is 2GB](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview.html#Quotas_and_Limits)

Here is the Java code that stores the image

```
private void putInBlobStore(final String mimeType, final byte[] data) throws IOException {
    final FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();
    final AppEngineFile file = fileService.createNewBlobFile(mimeType);
    final FileWriteChannel writeChannel = fileService.openWriteChannel(file, true);
    writeChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(data));
    writeChannel.closeFinally();
}
```

Comment: looks like splitting the data into smaller chunks made the trick. I still got the exception when I tried to store large dataStore record (which has hard limit of 1MB). since the exception stack trace was in a different thread, I thought it is the blobStore that make the problems. Google: you owe me several hours of debugging

Comment: If you'd included the stacktrace (or looked at it closely), we could've helped.

Comment: *UPDATE* the above code seems to work for me. It seems there is no longer a 1 mb limit...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum object size is 2 GB but each API call can only handle a maximum of 1 MB. At least for reading, but I assume it may be the same for writing. So you might try to split your writing of the object into 1 MB chunks and see if that helps.

Comment: I tried to split the writing to  several writeChannel.write invocations, but got same results

Comment: What does it mean "each API call can only handle a maximum of 1 MB" ? which API ? does it mean 1MB per (my app) request  ?

Comment: No, I would guess that it means more or less each function call, not the web request triggering you're code (otherwise there would really be no way to handle more than 1 MB).

Answer (score 5):

Here is how I read and write large files:

```
public byte[] readImageData(BlobKey blobKey, long blobSize) {
    BlobstoreService blobStoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory
            .getBlobstoreService();
    byte[] allTheBytes = new byte[0];
    long amountLeftToRead = blobSize;
    long startIndex = 0;
    while (amountLeftToRead > 0) {
        long amountToReadNow = Math.min(
                BlobstoreService.MAX_BLOB_FETCH_SIZE - 1, amountLeftToRead);

        byte[] chunkOfBytes = blobStoreService.fetchData(blobKey,
                startIndex, startIndex + amountToReadNow - 1);

        allTheBytes = ArrayUtils.addAll(allTheBytes, chunkOfBytes);

        amountLeftToRead -= amountToReadNow;
        startIndex += amountToReadNow;
    }

    return allTheBytes;
}

public BlobKey writeImageData(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
    FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();

    AppEngineFile file = fileService.createNewBlobFile("image/jpeg");
    boolean lock = true;
    FileWriteChannel writeChannel = fileService
            .openWriteChannel(file, lock);

    writeChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes));
    writeChannel.closeFinally();

    return fileService.getBlobKey(file);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As Brummo suggested above if you split it into chunks < 1MB it works. Here's some code.

```
public BlobKey putInBlobStoreString(String fileName, String contentType, byte[] filebytes) throws IOException {
    // Get a file service
    FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();
    AppEngineFile file = fileService.createNewBlobFile(contentType, fileName);
    // Open a channel to write to it
    boolean lock = true;
    FileWriteChannel writeChannel = null;
    writeChannel = fileService.openWriteChannel(file, lock);
    // lets buffer the bitch
    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(filebytes));
    byte[] buffer = new byte[524288]; // 0.5 MB buffers
    int read;
    while( (read = in.read(buffer)) > 0 ){ //-1 means EndOfStream
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer);
        writeChannel.write(bb);
    }
    writeChannel.closeFinally();
    return fileService.getBlobKey(file);
}
```

Comment: There is a constant for the max blob fetch size in BlobstoreService.MAX_BLOB_FETCH_SIZE = 1015808.  I tested this in a local unit test and it works for both reading and writing.