# File upload with google app engine

Tags: gwt, file-upload, amazon-s3

I am developing an application on google app engine with gwt. There is a requirement for this application to store files(eg: pdf, msword,.zip ect). I tried to use amazon S3 in Google app engine. But it fails because app enigine does not allow me to write file handling code if the app is running on Google app engine. One another option I tried was using Blobstore which limit to store files lesser than 1Mb per API call. Is there any other option to store large files at least 10mb with Google app engine?

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:

1. Blobstore API is limited to 1Mb per API call. You could chunk up your file into multiple calls: [1MB quota limit for a blobstore object in Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522804/1mb-quota-limit-for-a-blobstore-object-in-google-app-engine/6716795#6716795)
2. Use Google Storage and it's [API](http://code.google.com/apis/storage/docs/getting-started.html).

Comment: Thanks Peter, Is there any example or a tutorial to show the method of accessing Google Storage with java? That will be a great help for me. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

When I store files with GAE I use next aproach:

1 In my JSP page create a form with file input:

```
    <form name="uploadFileForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <input type="file" name="fileData"/>
    </form>
```

2 Write a servlet/controller that read binary data from request

3 Write this data to DataStore (limited with 1MB) or into BlobStore (one call to API is limited with 1MB, but total file size can be up to 2GB). For files with size > 1MB you have to do few API calls.