# Copying Blobs from one AppEngine application to another

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

I used the functionality provided by Google App Engine to copy all data from one application to another. What wasn't transfered though were my Blobs. How can I make a copy of it to my new application?

Answer (score 1):

Blobs can be served. This means they can be fetched by your other application. See my answer to this question a couple of days ago:
[How to fetch image and save to blobstore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12733098/how-to-fetch-image-and-save-to-blobstore/12734112#12734112)

Within 6 months a tool will be available: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/features#Roadmap_Features